# Disable Razors default .cshtml handler in a ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-webpages

Does anyone know how to disable the .cshtml extension completely from an ASP.NET Web Application?

In essence I want to hijack the .cshtml extension and provide my own implementation based on a [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) host, although when I try to access the page.cshtml directly it appears to be running under an existing WebPages razor host that I'm trying to disable.

> Note: it looks like its executing 
>   .cshtml pages under the
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor context
>   as the Microsoft.Data
>   Database is initialized. I don't even
>   have any Mvc or WebPages dlls
>   referenced, just System.Web.dll and a
>   local copy of System.Web.Razor with
>   RazorEngine.dll

I've created a new ASP.NET Web .NET 4.0 Application and have tried to clear all buildProviders and handlers as seen below:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <clear/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <buildProviders>
            <clear/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>

    <httpHandlers>
        <clear/>
        <add path="*" type="MyHandler" verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <clear/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <clear/>
        <add path="*" name="MyHandler" type="MyHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Although even with this, when I visit any **page.cshtml** page it still bypasses My wildcard handler and tries to execute the page itself.

Basically I want to remove all traces of .cshtml handlers/buildProviders/preprocessing so I can serve the .cshtml pages myself, anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to turn off ASP.NET webpages, you can set this flag in app settings:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to register your own custom `ViewEngine` in the `Application_Start` method. Scott Hanselman [blogged a sample](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) that uses a custom ViewEngine for mobile devices, but the ideas should be the same for what you're trying to do.

**Edit (again)**: [David Fowler suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483663/how-can-i-disable-remove-the-webpagehttpmodule-from-asp-net-4-0-web-applications/6487792#6487792):

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

I always wondered what that setting was for, but never got around to investigating! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines requires a dependency to MVC - I really want to remove all deps and existing behaviour.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you remove cshtml from the [`RazorCodeLanguages.Languages` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.razorcodelanguage.languages%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)?

Comment: Nope, it still tries to run but I get this exception now: http://pastebin.com/SPvLfn8G - It looks like WebPageHttpModule is the issue, do you know how I could remove it?

Comment: You should be able to clear that in the same was as you did the httpHandlers in your web.config sample (see edit in answer): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164632.aspx

Comment: Yeah doesn't work either (has no effect) - I think it's because they're being dynamically registered using the new PreApplicationStartMethod http://goo.gl/ysNb0

Comment: Hmmm, fail :-( Then I'm out of ideas. I'm curious though, so I did ask on Twitter though, in case any of the MS ASP.NET guys might be able to help http://twitter.com/#!/DanTup/status/84943521408229376

Comment: Hey cool thx, BTW I've created a new question with just trying to remove the WebPageHttpModule at: http://goo.gl/Hv8Vc