# Routing requests that end in ".cshtml" to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, routes

(This is [cross-posted](http://forums.asp.net/post/4571522.aspx) to the ASP.NET forms)

I'm working on the [WebGit .NET](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet) project, and we are close to a "1.0" release.  However, I'm having trouble getting my "Browse" controller (which pulls files out of the repository) to serve-up ".cshtml" files.

I originally had trouble with ".config" and ".cs" files as well, but I fixed that with this in the web.config:

```xml
  <location path="browse">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
            <clear />
          </fileExtensions>
          <hiddenSegments>
            <clear />
          </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

The routing that should be handling this request (that is successfully routing everything else) is:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "View Blob",
    "browse/{repo}/blob/{object}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "Browse", action = "ViewBlob", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now, whenever I try to access a URL that ends in ".cshtml", it gives a 404, even though my request should have been handled by the "Browse" controller.  The files I'm serving-up do not exist on disk, but are instead pulled from a git repository as blobs.  Every other file extension that I have tried works just fine.

How can I fix this behavior?

---

**EDIT:** I have tried disabling WebPages like so:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

But that appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a quick workaround, you can put a temporary browse.cshtml file at your application root and put this inside your web.config, 
add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"

Comment: Through WebMatrix Routing,, http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior#Creating_More_Readable_and_Searchable_URLs

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in ASP.NET WebPages, which gets implicitly loaded when you are using MVC 3. I don't think there is a straightforward way of disabling this behavior. The only workaround is to use a different extension (specifically, one that is not listed via [WebPageHttpHandler.GetRegisteredExtensions()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagehttphandler.getregisteredextensions%28v=VS.99%29.aspx))

This will be fixed in MVC 4, however. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Is there a bug tracker where this is registered?

Comment: Well, it's tracked in our internal bug tracker - and the fix is already checked in :) But for other such bugs http://connect.microsoft.com or http://aspnet.codeplex.com are good places.

Comment: Imran has a solution that I have selected that is actually working for me.  You may want to let your other customers know that there is a work-around.